# Does 面对疾病，特别是癌症，也就是恶性肿瘤 not imply 癌症就是肿瘤?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

> **面对疾病，特别是癌症，也就是恶性肿瘤**，除了及早治疗，彻底消灭癌细胞，心态也很重要。开朗、乐观是战胜癌症的武器。据统计，因此而完全恢复健康的奇迹并不少见；而悲观情绪，却间接成了癌细胞的帮手，加快了癌细胞在我们体内的繁殖。
> <sub>HSK Coursebook 6上, listening, page 196 ([original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asQl3.jpg))</sub>

The above is the listening component of a HSK6 textbook.  The question is:

> (1) 请选出与所听内容一致的一项。
>
> A. 情绪对癌细胞的繁殖没什么影响 ✗
> B. 为了战胜癌症，我们要保持乐观心态 ✓
> C. 癌症的治疗与发现时间没有关系人 ✗
> D. 癌症就是肿瘤 ✗
> <sub>HSK Coursebook 6上, listening, page 13 ([original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg30b.jpg))</sub>

I chose answer D (癌症就是肿瘤), since I felt it was consistent with the part I highlighted in bold.  However, the correct answer is B.  I can see how B is consistent with the remainder of the text, despite not being explicitly spelled out.  But I don't understand how D is inconsistent with the text.

**Question**: Does 面对疾病，特别是癌症，也就是恶性肿瘤 not imply 癌症就是肿瘤?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

肿瘤 (tumors) can be 良性(benign) or 恶性 (malignant)

良性肿瘤(benign tumors)  and  恶性肿瘤 (malignant tumors) are not the same

恶性肿瘤 is a cancerous tumor but 癌症 ([cancer](https://www.cancer.gov/about-cancer/understanding/what-is-cancer)) doesn't always come in the form of tumor

> Cancerous tumors may also be called malignant tumors. Many cancers form solid tumors, but **cancers of the blood, such as leukemias, generally do not.** Benign tumors do not spread into, or invade, nearby tissues. When removed, benign tumors usually don't grow back, whereas cancerous tumors sometimes do.

- Cancers may or may not be tumorous
- Tumors may or may not be cancerous

> *Question: Does 面对疾病，特别是癌症，也就是恶性肿瘤 not imply 癌症就是肿瘤?*

Yes, the structure of the sentence is stating (not just implying) Cancers are malignant tumors.

I suspect the person who wrote the question knew the difference, therefore, he marked D as incorrect because cancer is not equal to tumors but didn't use the right word in his sentence

I would write the question as follow:

面对疾病，特别是癌症，特别是恶性(癌化)肿瘤

If answer D was "癌症就是恶性肿瘤", although it is factually wrong, it was still consistent with the article and should be an acceptable answer

癌症就是肿瘤 is incorrect for the reason of 'inconsistent object' (factually correct or not is irrelevant)

Comment: It is interesting. Cancers are malignant tumors is right, Cancers are tumors is wrong???

Comment: @KymoWang  就是 can imply equivalency.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the text ...癌症，也就是恶性肿瘤

The key word here is 恶性 malicious, malignant. Not all tumors are malicious; some are benign 良性. Benign tumors are not cancerous.

Answer D is not correct because it says "Cancer is tumors."

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical technique to test student's attention to detail.

Out of all, it is apparent that answers A and C can be strikes out immediately, and B and D both are seemly correct, however, we know there is only one of the two that can be the correct answer, now, it is time to re-exam the question and try to figure out the one with miss match word/phrase, or meaning. In Chinese, this is called "挑語病".

As others have suggested, answer D contains a miss-match, as not all 肿瘤 are symptoms of 癌症. Now re-read the question, we find that the majority of content is emphasizing the importance of remain optimistic, thus, answer B is the best/correct match.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right, but answer B is the topic of the part. Not all questions are reasonable, it is the fact.

Answer (score 0):

If there are 2 correct answers, choose the most correct one, or, the one relates more to the topic of the whole paragraph... the main idea is about how we handle tumors, but not about what is tumor.. One exam tip from my teachers.

And 就是 means "equals to, is exactly the same thing", which is not true. They are not equal.